# Segue to a ViewController from previous VC

Tags: swift

I have a View Controller (1) that lists some entities in a table. If the user wants to add a new entity they click and "add" button where they segue to VC2 (a view containing a form to fill in the necessary fields to add a new entity). After they add an entity at VC2 I want them to be automatically forwarded to the details screen VC3 related to the entity that they just added. Normally this detail screen VC3 is a segue from VC1 when they click on an existing entity from the table.

currently in VC2 I have

```
//go back to VC1
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
//Segue to VC3
VC1?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetail", sender: self)
```

The problem with this is the user sees the view change back to VC1 then changes to VC3 due to the "pop" and then segue.

If I omit the `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` and go directly to VC3 it works as expected except when the user uses the back button from VC3 where it returns them to VC2 which is the form they filled out but I really want them to skip VC2 and go back to VC1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have two obvious choices, both very easy.

- Either go ahead and push from VC2 to VC3 and then remove VC2 from the stack, by calling `setViewControllers(_:animated:)` with `[VC1,VC3`], or else...
- Change what happens when the user pops from VC3 so that we pop all the way down to VC1, by calling `popToRootViewController(animated:)`.